# Robocopy script to copy certain file names with space inbetween

Tags: robocopy

[image]I use the script to copy certain files  with file name having space in between. I tried serveral options but still in vain. Please help

```
robocopy "Z:\Software\Microsoft Office" %userprofile%\downloads\NEW_USB\Office *Office*^2016* /r:0 /w:0 /a-:sh
```

[image: 1robocopy]
[image]

Comment: Please remember that you can also contribute to this community that helps you. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, accept it and even upvote it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can't fix your command because you spaces in the filespec and I can't figure out what you are trying to rename to what.  You need to quote your filespec when it has spaces, such as

`"Office 2016 Standard 64Bit CHT"`  including the path as desired.

Or you can use some tool such as Beyond Compare.  I have my own tool, but if I link it here, it will be regarded as spamming.

EDIT

```
robocopy "Z:\Software\Microsoft Office" "%UserProfile%\Downloads\NEW_USB\Office" "*Office 2016*" /r:0 /w:0 /a-:sh
```

That is bracket the filespec with quotes.

Comment: There are over 20 Office installation files in my folder but only 5 installation files all start with "Office 2016 Pro....." "Office 2016 Standard...." etc which I want to copy only these 5 files. How to put this criteria (Office 2016) into the robocopy script to copy these 5 files only ?